# How to change systemctl file using shell script or boto in aws

Tags: systemd, aws

I have following systemctl file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow celery worker daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow worker
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which is running fine. However, I have to provide different name as i spin up machines, for example

```
ExecStart=/bin/airflow worker -q "nameOfWorker"
```

However, "nameOfWorker" is decided when I am starting instance depending upon requirement. I am starting instance from image which already have systemctl file.

I can ssh into machine using

```
ssh -i "opencpu-fin.pem" ubuntu@***-**-***-***-***.**-****-2.compute.amazonaws.com in shell script.
```

What should I do next? Any guidance will be appricated

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way. As you deploy these files, you might be able to edit them using `sed`. So your base configuration file could have the following lines:

```
...
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow worker -q "nameOfWorker"
Restart=on-failure
...
```

And you could have a script which switches out the string "nameOfWorker" for the intended name:

```
sed 's/nameOfWorker/${intendedName}/' YourBaseSystemd.service > NewlyMade.service
```

So you could have this line of code kick off as you provision new machines.